# htaccess redirect/rewrite help

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect `domain.com/1/file.php` to `domain.com/2/file.php` and `domain.com/1/pic.jpg` to `domain.com/2/pic.jpg` etc. I want to redirect the subdirectory while leaving to end file in tact. I'm finding it hard to look for a tutorial as I can't describe my problem easily in google. Could someone show me how to do this or direct me to a tutorial about it.

Thanks

Comment: You want rewrite or redirect?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9])/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ 2/$2.php
```

Using mod_rewrite...You can do the same thing for your images as well.  Essentially the regex expression will collect the value for a backreference.  so $1 and $2 since i put 2 regex expressions in there.

Of course, if you need a different match instead of domain.com/1/... you will need to have a regex pattern that matches (but you can just google the appropriate regex expressions you may need but i took your example literally)

Answer (score 0):

Try following for redirect. Replace `1` and `2` with respective subdirectories.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^1/(.*\.)(jpg|php) /2/$1$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```